# How do I get all files from a SharePoint URL path which has shared%20Documents in its path?

Tags: sharepoint, postman

I am trying to fetch all files from a folder in SharePoint. I am looking for all file stored under "Shared%20Ducuments" path.

I am doing a GET request for an URL in Postman: https://{server_name}/sites/{sub_site}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents')/Files

But it says:

```
    <m:code>-2147024809, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl</m:message>
```

My URL path for my SharePoint folder is :

https://{server_name}/sites/{sub_site}/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?AD={some extra long random mix of characters at the end}

Comment: Is there any update ? Did the answer resolove the issue ?

Comment: yes it worked. I don't know how to update the query as "resolved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this endpoint, prepend /sites/sub_site in GetFolderByRelativeUrl function:

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sub_sitename/Shared%20Documents')/Files
```